# S-N bond IR vibrations

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, spectroscopy, ir-spectroscopy, organosulfur-compounds

I am working on organosulfur compounds where i have S-N bonding, according to literature it might be having an ir vibration of 1100cm-1, could anyone confirm it with reference. (the complete bonding will be like S-S-N-C)
Thanks